# Render items in the list returned by a function (view)

Tags: python, django, django-templates

I have links displayed from a list but they are not parsed as 'clickable'

my template looks like this:

```
 <html>
 <body>
 <h2>All listing</h2> 
 {% for link in name %}
   <div>
     <ul>
    <li> {{ link }}</li>
     </ul>
   </div>
 {% endfor %}
 </body>
 </html>
```

I was hoping the above will return the links as clickable however I only see the raw html as follows:

```
<a href="http://www.businessghana.com/portal/jobs/index.php?op=getJobInfo&amp;id=103536">Sales Executives needed urgently in Accra</a>
<a href="http://www.businessghana.com/portal/jobs/index.php?op=getJobInfo&amp;id=120007">Direct Sales Officers</a>
<a href="http://www.businessghana.com/portal/jobs/index.php?op=getJobInfo&amp;id=120010">Fleet Engineer</a>
<a href="http://www.businessghana.com/portal/jobs/index.php?op=getJobInfo&amp;id=119866">Business Development Manager</a>
<a href="http://www.businessghana.com/portal/jobs/index.php?op=getJobInfo&amp;id=119846">Administrative &amp; Accounts Assistant Urgently Needed</a>
<a href="http://www.businessghana.com/portal/jobs/index.php?op=getJobInfo&amp;id=119772">Quality Control Officer</a>
```

I was getting what I want when I use HttpResponse to show the links using the view below

```
def businessghana(request):
    site = "http://www.businessghana.com/portal/jobs"
    hdr = {'User-Agent' : 'Mozilla/5.0'}
    req = urllib2.Request(site, headers=hdr)
    jobpass = urllib2.urlopen(req)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(jobpass)
    for tag in soup.find_all('a', href = True):
        tag['href'] = urlparse.urljoin('http://www.businessghana.com/portal/', tag['href'])
    html = map(str, soup.find_all('a', href = re.compile('.getJobInfo')))
    return HttpResponse(html)
```

but once I added a template, I'm not getting it that way anymore.
How can I get my links already parsed as clickable instead of raw html?

Thanks in advance and happy holidays to everyone,

Max

Comment: Apply `safe` filter for each item: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#safe

Comment: @mariodev That is exactly what I needed.. If you can put it up as the answer, I will accept it. Thanks.